# Assigning values in for loop in R

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to populate a list iteratively using a for loop. I don't typically use R, but the method I needed has not yet been implemented in Python, and I didn't want to implement it myself. The code is as follows:

```
path = '/PATH/'
files <- dir(path, pattern = '.txt')

#sampleList <- list()
#pValues <- list()
pValues <- rep(NA, length(files))
sampleList <- rep(NA, length(files))
count = 1
for(file in files){ 
  clonPath = paste('/PATH/', file, sep = '', header = NULL)
  clonal <- read.csv(clonPath, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ',')
  subs = paste('/PATH/', file, sep = '', header = NULL)
  subPath = paste(subs, '.subclonal.csv', sep = '')
  subclonal <- read.csv(subPath, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ',')
  colnames(clonal) <- c('X', 'Count', 'Start', 'End', 'Chr')
  colnames(subclonal) <- c('X', 'Count', 'Start', 'End', 'Chr')
  clonalCounts = clonal$Count
  subclonalCounts = subclonal$Count
  if(length(subclonalCounts != length(clonalCounts))){ 

    pValues[count] <- 0
    sampleList[count] <- file
    count = count + 1
    #print(p)

  }
  else{
    p <- chisq.test(subclonalCounts, clonalCounts, simulate.p.value = T) 
    pValues[count]<<-chisq.test(subclonalCounts, clonalCounts, simulate.p.value = T)[3]
    print(chisq.test(subclonalCounts, clonalCounts, simulate.p.value = T)[3])
    sampleList[count] <- file 
    count = count + 1
    print(p[3])
  }
}
```

Basically, when I run this code, the value for p never updates, and the print statements (put in when debugging (poorly)) don't print anything. I'd like to assign the p-value for the chi-sq test to pValues, but it doesn't seem to be working.

edit: I have also manually checked that >=1 of my input files would fail the first if statement, and be evaluated in the else statement.

Comment: Nice code! Do you have a question?

Comment: Oh jeez, I forgot to ask. I'll edit it in to the main post. Basically, when I run this code, the value for p never updates, and the print statements (put in when debugging (poorly)) don't print anything.

Comment: Without seeing your data.  Most likely subconalCounts is a vector while length(clonalCounts) is a single value.  Thus the if statement will be FALSE for the first element and never evaluate to TRUE

Comment: @Dave2e: You were right. I forgot to close that bracket. Thank you!

Comment: @Berimbolo is your problem solved? If so, please post your answer using box below (you can [answer your own questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) and [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/312562), so it no longer appears on list of unresolved questions. If no, please edit your question to clarify what exact issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 if(length(subclonalCounts != length(clonalCounts)))
```

Is missing a parenthesis around length(subclonalCounts)